How to handle transaction, locks & isolation level in sequelize?
I am trying to understand about Transaction, Lock & Isolation Level in sequelize. Say I have a route where I do multiple inserts to user table.
const transactionHandler = f => {
    const callback = async (req, res, next) => {
        const response = await sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
            const result = await f(req, res, next, transaction);
            return result;
        });
        return response;
    };
    return callback;
};

router.get('/acid', transactionHandler(acid));

export const acid = async (req, res, next, transaction) => {
    await User.bulkCreate([req.body], { transaction, individualHooks: true });
    await setTimeout(30 * 1000);
    return res.status(200).json({ done: true });
};

The above is my /acid route, which will last about 30 seconds to be completed. So, the created records inside the transaction will only be committed after 30 seconds. As I have implemented managed transaction in this case, I don't have to manually commit here. I want to have a constraint in user table which is on javascript level as it is a lot complex to implement. Suppose uniqueness of username in this scenario.
const checkUsername = async (username, transaction) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ 
        attributes: ['id'],
        where: { username },
    });
    if(user)
        throw new ValidationError(`Username '${username}' already exists.`);
};

User.beforeCreate(async (user, options) => {
    await checkUsername(user.username, options.transaction);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, SALT_ROUNDS);
});

Say my backend received two requests having 10 records in the body. The body of both records have the same usernames.
// Body of Request A
[ { username: "cole" }, { username: "jeremy" }, { username: "alex" } ]

// Body of Request B
[ { username: "cole" }, { username: "jeremy" }, { username: "alex" } ]

The problem comes here. I received the Request A at 0 second and Request B at 10 seconds. At that time, transaction A is not yet committed to the database but all of the user records have been inserted. Since the records of transaction A are not committed, when checking for duplicate usernames by transaction B. There is no duplicate. So the records from transaction B are inserted into the database as well. After both transactions have been committed, I have duplicate users in my table. What I want to do is that I want trasaction B to wait until transaction A finishes. How can I handle this in sequelize?

Please update the post with the table DDL. From the description in the post, I'm assuming that the database doesn't have a unique index on username. Do not rely on application code to enforce uniqueness or referential integrity constraints.
